# How to hide a mobile keyboard's upper bar?

Tags: swift, input, webview, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a simple Swift web view application which loads an input (of type text). Everything is fine, but I want to hide the bar marked with red circle in the picture - [keyboard's bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rp3r.png). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) there are default keyboard types which can be accessed, but apparently not changed themself.